# how to put elements from model into select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a database Country filled with (obvious) contries. now i would like to display them in the select_tag in my view (like a drop down list).

i tried puttin in options_for_select sth like @show_me_the_countries_mama.each do |f| ('[' + f.printable_name + ']' + ','). this would list countries each one of them in [] brackets and with spaces in normal view. but it doesnt work in options_for_select for doing the drop down list.

i have:

'get' do %>
Country:

how can i solve this? i somehow have to put an array of countries in options_for_select and now i am asking how should i do this. shoud i write separate method in the model for getting the proper array of countries and then inserting them here or..?

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001625) tag:

```
<%= collection_select :object, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :printable_name %>
```

Where :id and :printable_name are the methods passed to each model in Country.all to get the value and display parts of a select option, respectively.

You could also look at [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) for *very* easy form generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`country_select`](http://github.com/rails/country_select) plugin so that you don't have to maintain any of that in your DB. If you go the formtastic route you'll still need a plugin like `country_select`.